# Are locked notes in the Notes.app are encrypted on the local host?

Tags: icloud, encryption, notes.app

Anyone has a clue? I know they are encrypted on the servers, but I would like to know if they are also particularly encrypted on my machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All user data on iOS devices is automatically encrypted. This includes any data stored in the Notes app.

Data on Mac computers is not encrypted by default, unless the individual app encrypts its data storage. It appears that data is stored in an unencrypted SQLite database, based on the fact there's a third-party [export tool available](https://github.com/jakwings/mac-notes-exporter).

Answer (score -1):

It is unnecessary as encryption is to protect data from "interception" while be moved between device and server or while on server.

Your protection of notes on your device is your passcode / fingerprint.

Learn more at:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303

Comment: Er, no. Encryption is to prevent data from being accessed by unauthorized parties regardless of where it is, and whether it's in transit or not. The link you provided does not answer the question because it does not address whether data is encrypted while cached on the local machine.

Comment: @user261147 tubedogg, You are correct - my research was incomplete. The following link addresses the encryption of data while being transferred to / from the iPad/iPhone: [link] (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202303) This next link addresses the encryption of data while on an iPhone or iPad:  [link] (https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-encrypt-your-iphone)